# dj-stripe [python module] how do i sync my plans from stripe to django?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I have installed and tried it. but there is nowhere in the documentation any mentions on how to sync the plans and subscriptions from stripe to the django objects.

Comment: You need to build a model that mirrors the structure of a Stripe object or you need to build a model that adequately encompasses the information you want and then add them to your database manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took reference from [this github issue answer](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/issues/624#issuecomment-354546495):

```
from djstripe.models import Plan

for plan in Plan.api_list():
    Plan.sync_from_stripe_data(plan)
```

Logic is similar for the `Subscription` model.

Comment: Thank you, david. That was not implemented when I asked the question but seems to have been implemented now. Great!

Comment: Please "tick" my answer as well. :)